# Qbs, How can .h.in files be configured on Windows?

Tags: c++, qbs

I have a C/C++ project that was written to be configured with `CMake`. I'm trying to learn `Qbs` by converting it to use `Qbs`. It happen there are `.h.in` files that in `CMake` are configured using the `configure_file()` function. For example in `CMake` a file named `bson-version.h.in` is converted to `bson-version.h` using the below code.

```
configure_file (
   "${SOURCE_DIR}/src/bson/bson-version.h.in"
   "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/bson/bson-version.h"
)
```

How can this be achieved in Qbs? I'm on Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this. You can easily implement it yourself, though. Here's a sketch (untested):

```
Product {
    // ...
    Group {
        files: ["src/bson/bson-version.h.in"]
        fileTags: ["header.in"]
    }
    // ...
    cpp.includePaths: [buildDirectory + "/generated_headers"]
    Rule {
        inputs: ["header.in"]
        Artifact {
            filePath: "generated_headers/bson-version.h"
            fileTags: ["hpp"]
        }
        prepare: {
            // Create JavaScriptCommand and do the replacements
            // via qbs.TextFile. 
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if the .in file refers to cmake variables, you will have to define equivalent qbs properties in your project and consider them in the rule.